# zeros of linear recurence sequences

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, computer-science

Given a linear recurrence sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$, how to decide whethere there are infinitely many zeros, or there are only finitely many ones?

Comment: There is no way to answer such a vague question. What kind of recurrence relation do you have?

Comment: If it's a linear homogeneous constant-coefficient recurrence, the Skolem-Mahler-Lech Theorem is helpful. See, e.g., http://cfranc.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/the-skolem-mahler-lech-theorem/

Comment: thanks. I mean given a linear recurrence relation, e.g., $a_{n+m}= \sum_{i=1}^{m-1} c_ia_{n+i}$, and $c_i$ are all integers, and $a_1, \dots, a_{m-1}$ are given integers.

Comment: If you want to be sure I see your comment, you have to put @Gerry in there somewhere. Anyway, yes, that's a linear homogeneous constant-coefficient recurrence. I trust that by now you've had a look at Skolem-Mahler-Lech. Has it been helpful?

Answer (score 4):

The *characteristic polynomial* of your recurrence is $$x^{m-1}-c_{m-1}x^{m-2}-\cdots-c_1$$

Here's something that follows from the Skolem-Mahler-Lech Theorem: if the recurrence has infinitely many zeros, then the characteristic polynomial has two distinct roots whose ratio is a root of unity.

Careful: this is *not* an "if and only if".

Another good source is Chapter 2 of the book [Recurrence Sequences](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=SURV-104) by Graham Everest, Alf Van Der Poorten, Igor Shparlinski and Thomas Ward.